# How do I avoid creating hundreds of files.vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, vue-router

I am building a website with a lot of items.
So the path is like:

`example.com/catalog/indoor/fireplace/awesome-one`

And currently I am creating hundreds and hundreds of `Vue` instances:

```
AwesomeOne.vue
AnotherOne.vue
YetAnotherThing.vue
...
AhundredthThing.vue
```

And all they have inside is a filtered array and passing a prop to the reusable component which uses data from `Vuex` storage.
And so I am thinking, is there a way to avoid creating so many `Vue` files? I kinda sorted the problem with `Nuxt.js`, but it only automatically generates routes which makes the development slightly easier. But I still have to create a lot of files with nearly identical code inside (it's literally just 3 words difference: the name of the computed property, the filter option and the name of the prop).

I was thinking about some computed property which would assign an URL dynamically, using data from `Vuex.state`. But I can't put things together.

as requested posting the code:
Catalog.vue

```
<template>
  <v-main>
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        v-for="category in categories"
        :key="category.i"
      >
        <v-card
          router
          :to="category.link"
        >
          <v-img
            height="250"
            width="250"
            :src="category.img"
          />
          <v-card-title>
            {{ category.name }}
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
computed: {
  categories () {
    return this.$store.state.categories
  }
}
}
</script>
```

CatalogCategories.vue (having 5 of them)

```
<template>
  <v-sheet>
    <h1>Изделия для дома</h1>
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        v-for="indoorItem in indoorItems"
        :key="indoorItem.i"
      >
        <a :href="indoorItem.link">{{ indoorItem.name }}</a>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    subCategories () {
      return this.$store.state.subCategories
    },
    indoorItems () {
      return this.subCategories.filter((category) => category.type === "indoor" || category.type === "bothdoor");
    },    
  }

}
</script>
```

Banquet.vue (one of the categories, having over 20 of them)

```
<template>
  <v-sheet>
    <h1>Банкетки</h1>
    <item-view :items="this.banquet" />
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
import ItemView from "../../../components/ItemView.vue"
export default {

components: { ItemView },
computed: {
  items () {
    return this.$store.state.items
  },
  banquet () {
      return this.items.filter((item) => item.type === "banquet");
    },    
}
}
</script>
```

ItemView.Vue (reusable component)

```
<template>
  <v-sheet>
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.i"
      >
        <v-card
          route
          :to="item.path"
        >
          <v-img
            width="250"
            height="250"
            :src="item.img"
          />
          <v-card-title> {{ item.name }} </v-card-title>
          <v-card-subtitle> Цена: {{ item.price }} грамм конфет му-му </v-card-subtitle>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        items: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        },
    },
        
    }


</script>
```

IndividualItem.vue (I'll have to create over 100 of them)

```
<template>
  <v-sheet>
    <v-card>
      <individual-item-view :items="this.obossana" />
      <v-card />
    </v-card>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
import IndividualItemView from '../../../../components/IndividualItemView.vue'
export default {
  components: { IndividualItemView },
    
    computed: {
  items () {
    return this.$store.state.items
  },
  obossana () {
      return this.items.filter((item) => item.title === "obossana");
    },  

}
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

IndividualItemView.vue (reusable component)

```
<template>
  <v-sheet>
    <v-card
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.i"
    >
      <v-card-title> {{ item.name }} </v-card-title>
      
      <expandable-image
        class="image"
        close-on-background-click       
        :src="item.img"
      />
      <v-card-subtitle> Цена: {{ item.price }} раз послать тебя ко всем чертям </v-card-subtitle>
      <v-card-text> {{ item.description }} </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    mounted() {
    const viewportMeta = document.createElement('meta');
    viewportMeta.name = 'viewport';
    viewportMeta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1';
    document.head.appendChild(viewportMeta);
  },
props: {
        items: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.image {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

And little snippet from Vuex store:

```
 {
        name: "Обоссаная банкетка",
        title: "obossana",
        type: "banquet",
        path: "/catalog/indoor/banquet/obossana",
        price: "215361",
        img:
          "https://b2.3ddd.ru/media/cache/tuk_model_custom_filter_ru/model_images/0000/0000/0079/79546.53239b3804d0a.jpeg",
        description: "blah blah blah",
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.

`_view.vue` for individual item view:

```
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData() {
    const items = await fetch(
      'API URL here'
    ).then((res) => res.json())

    return { items }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      params: this.$route.params.view,
      title: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter((item) => item.title === this.$route.params.view)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

turned out it was pretty easy. All I had to do is to fetch the hard coded data (I decided to use API because in the future I'll have to add more items and I believe it gonna be easier if I use API) and filter it that the `item.title` matches the route `$route.params.view`

Inside the `template` tag (`_view.vue` file) I had:

```
<template>
  <v-main>
    <h1>API: items</h1>
    <h2>'/catalog/_subcategory/_individualitem/_view.vue' here</h2>
    <h3>params.view: {{ params }}</h3>
    <v-card v-for="item in filteredItems" :key="item.i">
      <v-avatar size="200">
        <img :src="item.img" alt="картинка предмета" />
      </v-avatar>
      <v-card-title>
        {{ item.name }} and item.title: {{ item.title }}
      </v-card-title>
      <v-card-subtitle>Цена: {{ item.price }} сантиметров</v-card-subtitle>
      <v-card-text> {{ item.description }} </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-main>
</template>
```

`h1`, `h2`, `h3` tags helped me to figure out (by displaying) values of variables.

The file tree is (the root is catalog itself):

```
├── index.vue
├── _subcategory
│   ├── _individualitem
│   │   └── _view.vue
│   └── _items.vue
└── _type.vue
```

And a little bit of `api.json`:

```
{
    "title": "stremnaya-arka",
    "path": "/catalog/outdoor/arcs/stremnaya-arka",
    "name": "Стрёмная арка",
    "type": "arcs",    
}
```

Might be a bit confusing with the file names, but I hope it is not.

I hope it'll help some other newbie who struggles as much as me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, and there's a few different ways that you can solve this.  I'll show the simplest way IMO, which is to continue to use props and push the hardcoded data you have further and further up the component hierarchy.

I'll use `IndividualItem.vue` as the example, since it's by far the most obvious how to apply it:

```
<template>
  <v-sheet>
    <v-card>
      <individual-item-view :items="this.items" />
      <v-card />
    </v-card>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
import IndividualItemView from "../../../../components/IndividualItemView.vue";
export default {
  components: { IndividualItemView },

  // Add a prop for the title
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  // Filter only store items with that title
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.$store.state.items.filter(
        (item) => item.title === this.title
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

To use it, all you need to do is the following:

```
<IndividualItem title="obossana" />
```

Using props in this manner is what actually allows you to create and use reusable components.  There's also all kinds of different strategies that you can apply for passing props.

For example, rather than passing the `title`, you could instead pass the `items`, which would give the user of you `IndividualItem` component even more control over what items they want to show.

Here's a quick demo of that too:

```
<template>
  <v-sheet>
    <v-card>
      <individual-item-view :items="this.items" />
      <v-card />
    </v-card>
  </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
import IndividualItemView from "../../../../components/IndividualItemView.vue";
export default {
  components: { IndividualItemView },

  // Any items may be passed in, allowing the user to group
  // different items together however they need.
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Then, the user of the component might do (Note: you could create `obossanaItems` the exact same way you already do, just in the parent components scope):

```
<IndividualItem :items="obossanaItems" />
```

As a final piece of closing advice, which may be the piece that you're missing,  almost all hardcoded data (like `title: obossana`) should come directly from either your page components, or your API, which is what ultimately allows you to create reusable components.

For example, the page component in charge of rendering pages for `example.com/catalog/indoor/fireplace/awesome-one` should be in charge of supplying all its child components with the information they need to render the proper data.

This isn't the only method, but it's definitely the easiest to get started with, and it's what I'd recommend instead of creating specific components for each category, sub-category, etc.

As I mentioned at the beginning of this post, you're already very close, you just need to continue abstracting the specific data items to parent components.  There's other features of Vue and Nuxt, like [Vuex getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html), that can also help to make the specific filtering calls reusable as well, but that's getting into another topic.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit busy learning Nuxt.js. Now I got some time to have a look over here. And I think we've got misunderstanding over here.
I do know how to pass props and create reusable components.
The thing is that I have to actually create all the files: `catalog.vue` which will have `indoor.vue` nested inside, which will have `fireplaces.vue` nested inside(which has reusable `ItemView.vue` nested inside), which will have `awesome-fireplace.vue` nested inside (which has reusable `IndividualItemView.vue` nested inside).

Comment: My problem is that I don't want to create 100x `files.vue` with identical code inside with the only 1 difference as a different prop passed into reusable component inside of them.
`fireplace.vue`: `<IndividualItemView :items="this.awesomeOne"` 
And then I'll have to create another file `shelf.vue`: `<IndividualItemView :items="this.rottenShelf"` 
And so on, 100 files for catalog with the only 1 difference as a different prop. Is that alright or there's a way I can avoid that and sorta generate views without actually creating files.

Comment: Okay I found what I've been looking for. It called dynamic pages. 
https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing-dynamic-pages/
I hope I can figure out how to apply it :)